# Torque and angular frequency of a merry-go-round

Tags: physics, rotations

[image: The problem.]

I have been trying to approach this by finding the gravitational torque of the person on the merry-go-round, however I can't find a way to relate that to angular velocity in the given circumstances.

If this problem requires angular momentum to solve, then I won't need to know the solution because it won't be on my final, however I still want to make sure that I'm not missing something.

Comment: I don't think this question expects you to take gravity into account in any way. Angular momentum and its conservation is definitely the most straightforward way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an A-Level problem.

Assuming no friction, by conservation of angular momentum

\begin{align*}
  I_1 \omega_1 &= I_2 \omega_2 \\
  (150+65\times 0.5^2) 1.7 &= (150+65\times 1.5^2) \omega_2 \\
  \omega_2 &= 0.95 \text{ rad/s}
\end{align*}